# Updating fixed height in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

In adobe edge animate when we use responsive scaling it scales whole website and preserves the aspect ratio of images and other content. I want to know that how can i update the fixed height which is specified in the .js document and how to find what is the current height of my web page, when it has been  scaled by the responsive scaling script of adobe edge animate in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

`window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowSize);`

You can use this event listener to call a function to update your dimensions.  I don't know which element's height you want to be resetting, but you can use this to reset the positions or heights and widths of any element by targeting the element and changing its css:

```
function updateWindowSize() {
   var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
   var winHeight = window.innerHeight;
   $('.someElement').css({height: winHeight / 2 + "px"});
}
```

Here's an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9fgk09w/)